# Wait until callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I've got an array with audio-files, to play all one by one.
I'm using a javascript player, that will play the audio and provides a callback when finished.

```
for (i = 0; i < audioFiles.length; i++) {
    PlayAudio(audioFiles[i], function(){
        alert('complete file #' + i);
    });
}
```

But my problem now, how to do this one by one. The snippet above will start several audio-files and play them parallel. What is the best solution, to wait until a callback is fired?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: "Don't make functions in a loop" is one of the errors you get when you put your code through http://jshint.com/.

Comment: You cannot "wait" in JS, if you mean "block execution". The only thing you can do is put the code for the next actions (here: load the next file) in the callback itself. Use a recursive approach instead of a loop.

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async this library is the answer to all your "async" questions, please check it. I have save lot of time thanks to this library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many solutions.  Waiting until the callback fires seems like a good solution.

```
function playAudioFile(index) {
  PlaidAudio(audioFiles[index], function () {
    var next = index + 1;
    if (next < audioFiles.length) {
      playAudioFile(index+1);
    }
  });
}

function playAudioFiles() {
  playAudioFile(0);
}
```

Side note:

If you're looking for a more generic way to run tasks serially, you should look at promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), or [here](http://www.codeducky.org/q-serial/) (though the last post is only for AngularJS).

Comment: I'd add an `else` statement to log (or execute another function) once the whole playlist is done.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy may use the async library. This way I solve every problem with asynchrony. In this case you could use an "each" sentence:

```
async.each(
    // List of item
    audioFiles, 

    // Function to apply to each item
    function(index, callback){
        PlayAudio(audioFiles[index], function(){
            callback()
        });
    },

    // Function callback
    function(err,results){
        alert("Process finished");
    }
);
```

And if you want avoid parallelism, you may use "eachSeries" instead of "each"

```
async.eachSeries(
    // List of item
    audioFiles, 

    // Function to apply to each item
    function(index, callback){
        PlayAudio(audioFiles[index], function(){
            callback()
        });
    },

    // Function callback
    function(err,results){
        alert("Process finished");
    }
);
```

https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score -1):

You could use a combination of Promises and Generators to achieve what you want.  Using a combination of Promises and Generators will let you wait for each file to finish playing before playing the next while still leaving the thread open for user interaction or whatever you desire.

[This article](https://www.promisejs.org/generators/) has some good background to get started.